Would Like To Set Up Chrome Remote Desktop Access So It Doesn't Require a PIN or One-time Code
I need help setting up Chrome Remote Desktop on a client's PC.  They have already installed CDR on their PC.  I would like to access their PC anytime.  The PC is running all the time.  I don't want to enter a PIN or a one-time code when I access their PC.
I managed to do this with another client, but I've forgotten the instructions they followed.  I recall that they started by creating a new Gmail account.  Then they started Gmail, and logged in to the new Gmail account.  Then they started CRD and went through some steps to allow me to access their PC remotely.  After that, all I needed to do was to start Gmail, sign into the Gmail account they created, start CRD, and select Remote Access in the upper left corner of the screen.  Then I would see an icon for the client's PC, and I could click it to gain access to the PC.
I hope someone can tell me the specific steps the client would need to follow to allow me to gain remote access to their PC without entering a PIN or onetime code.

Have you done any research to find the documentation for how to do this and followed it?

Yes I did.  I didn't see the setup steps to follow that would let me access the client's PC in the way I would like to, which is the following: (1) Start Gmail on my PC; (2) log in to the gmail account they used when they did the setup; (3) start CRD; (4)  select Remote Access, (5) click the icon showing their PC.  I could only find documentation that required a PIN or one-time code.
